# ASP.Net Searches for Assmblies in wrong location

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, .net-assembly

I've got an application that works perfectly on Server A, but fails to load a DLL from the Bin folder on server B.

The error given on the webpage is:

Could not load file or assembly 'DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

I've checked the following so far, and they're identical or have non-relevant changes:

- Machine.config All Web.configs (Those on C:\, and root of inetpub, and in the application)
- Permissions on the file Application itself (checked with Beyond compare binary compare)
- IIS Version (6)
- Server OS (Server 2003, upgrading is not an option)
- Cleared every cache I could find
- Rebooted multiple times

Where do I go from here?

Here's what the Output from Process Monitor looks like:

**Good machine:**

> 3:56:14.6634916 PM    w3wp.exe    3912    QueryOpen   D:\inetpub\Application\bin\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll   SUCCESS CreationTime: 2/3/2016 2:56:02 PM, LastAccessTime: 2/3/2016 3:53:07 PM, LastWriteTime: 3/20/2012 3:34:38 AM, ChangeTime: 2/3/2016 2:56:02 PM, AllocationSize: 181,248, EndOfFile: 181,248, FileAttributes: A

**Bad Machine:**

> 3:03:20.5299875 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   D:\inetpub\Application\bin\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll   SUCCESS CreationTime: 2/3/2016 2:58:35 PM, LastAccessTime: 2/3/2016 2:58:35 PM, LastWriteTime: 3/20/2012 3:34:38 AM, ChangeTime: 2/3/2016 2:58:35 PM, AllocationSize: 181,248, EndOfFile: 181,248, FileAttributes: A
>   3:03:20.5503911 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Application\751e867b\de1d3917\assembly\dl3\35c61e5a\000b1bab_7c06cd01\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll  SUCCESS CreationTime: 2/2/2016 3:33:17 PM, LastAccessTime: 2/3/2016 9:51:53 AM, LastWriteTime: 3/20/2012 3:34:38 AM, ChangeTime: 2/2/2016 3:38:17 PM, AllocationSize: 184,320, EndOfFile: 181,248, FileAttributes: A
>   3:03:20.6090648 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Application\751e867b\de1d3917\assembly\dl3\35c61e5a\000b1bab_7c06cd01\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll  SUCCESS CreationTime: 2/2/2016 3:33:17 PM, LastAccessTime: 2/3/2016 9:51:53 AM, LastWriteTime: 3/20/2012 3:34:38 AM, ChangeTime: 2/2/2016 3:38:17 PM, AllocationSize: 184,320, EndOfFile: 181,248, FileAttributes: A
>   3:03:20.6094970 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Application\751e867b\de1d3917\assembly\dl3\35c61e5a\000b1bab_7c06cd01\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll  SUCCESS CreationTime: 2/2/2016 3:33:17 PM, LastAccessTime: 2/3/2016 9:51:53 AM, LastWriteTime: 3/20/2012 3:34:38 AM, ChangeTime: 2/2/2016 3:38:17 PM, AllocationSize: 184,320, EndOfFile: 181,248, FileAttributes: A
>   3:03:20.6156343 PM w3wp.exe    3916    CreateFile  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Application\751e867b\de1d3917\assembly\temp\AD9NLH9SDO\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.DLL SUCCESS Desired Access: Write Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
>   3:03:20.6157574 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Application\751e867b\de1d3917\assembly\temp\AD9NLH9SDO\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.DLL SUCCESS CreationTime: 2/2/2016 3:33:17 PM, LastAccessTime: 2/3/2016 9:51:53 AM, LastWriteTime: 3/20/2012 3:34:38 AM, ChangeTime: 2/2/2016 3:38:17 PM, AllocationSize: 184320, EndOfFile: 181248, FileAttributes: A
>   3:03:24.9587326 PM w3wp.exe    3916    RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\v4.0_policy.5.1.DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI__879da714589ba9ea NAME NOT FOUND
>   3:03:24.9587462 PM w3wp.exe    3916    RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\policy.5.1.DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI__879da714589ba9ea  NAME NOT FOUND
>   3:03:24.9592127 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI\v4.0_5.1.3.2__879da714589ba9ea\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll   PATH NOT FOUND
>   3:03:24.9592589 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI\v4.0_5.1.3.2__879da714589ba9ea\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll PATH NOT FOUND
>   3:03:24.9593042 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI\v4.0_5.1.3.2__879da714589ba9ea\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll  PATH NOT FOUND
>   3:03:24.9593387 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI\5.1.3.2__879da714589ba9ea\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll  PATH NOT FOUND
>   3:03:24.9593799 PM w3wp.exe    3916    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI\5.1.3.2__879da714589ba9ea\DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll    PATH NOT FOUND
>   ...

Comment: Are the IIS configurations the same? Example would be one AppPool set to x64 and the other set to x86.

Comment: Yes. I even compared the entire IIS configuration by exporting it with adsutil and comparing in beyond compare. It was very noisy but the sections for the apps were the same.

Comment: What platform (x86/x64 bit) both server OS are? What mode (x86/x64 bit) both app pools are running with? Did you try to disassemble DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll assembly from bin folder of application on both server?

Comment: Both are on 32bit server2003, so only 32bit pools. And the dlls in both folders are binary the same, so if I had corruption it would have shown up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be my error- I missed a Visual C++ 2010 redistributable dependency in the list of references for DocuWare.Remoting.SSL.SSPI.dll.